# Dojo: parsing HTML-content on iframe load

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dojo

Image that we have a simple Dojo HTML-template file with inline JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ..
  ready(function() {
    var url = "{% url 'link_to_iframe_content' %}";

    target.src = url;
    on(target, 'load', function() {
      doSomething();
    });
  });
  --
</script>
<div>
  <iframe id="target"><iframe>
</div>
```

iframe contains dojo widgets e.g. `data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button` which are not getting parsed when iframe loaded.

What would be the correct way to handle this situation? Should `dojo/parser` be explicitly called or there is better solution?

Comment: I would first warn you that cross-frame scripting can get rather hairy rather fast due to switching global contexts, so I'd say the ideal way to handle this would be to avoid it altogether if possible.

Comment: @KenFranqueiro Unfortunately, this option is not available at moment. What I am trying right now is: create widget ouside iframe and then pass it inisde, create CSS element and pass it inside iframe (so it gets proper styling).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest way is for the page loaded into the `<iframe>` to have a `<script>` tag to load dojo.js, and to `require()` and run the dojo/parser, just like a top level dojo page would do.